# RewriteMap with text option always returns no result

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I'm going to self-answer this question because I ran into it and couldn't find a single Google result to help, so hopefully this can save some future person some time.

In Apache2.2, I have a RewriteMap fashioned like this, to redirect to a url if a particular query string argument is present:

```
RewriteMap redirect "txt:/etc/arbitrary1/arbitrary2/redirect.txt"

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)foo=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond ${redirect:%1} !^$
RewriteRule ^.*$ ${redirect:%1} [301,L]
```

And `/etc/arbitrary1/arbitrary2/redirect.txt`:

```
foo http://hello.invalid/somepath/1  # 1
bar http://hello.invalid/somepath/2  # 2
baz http://hello.invalid/somepath/3  # 3
```

The problem I ran into was that, no matter which of "foo, bar, baz" I used, the `${redirect:%1}` directive would return blank (i.e. "no match"). This was regardless of the format of `redirect.txt`. SEE BELOW FOR WHAT I DISCOVERED.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem ended up being that the intermediate directory `/etc/arbitrary1` did not have execute permissions for the `www-data` user. The reason this took so long to discover was because, evidently, the suid from root takes place *after* the check for file existence. That is, if I changed `RewriteMap redirect "txt:/etc/arbitrary1/arbitrary2/redirect.txt"` to `RewriteMap redirect "txt:/etc/arbitrary1/arbitrary2/doesnotexist.txt"`, Apache would give an error on restart, which indicated that it had no problem statting `/etc/arbitrary1/arbitrary2/redirect.txt` when config loaded. Because Apache found it on start, I then assumed it could also access it during execution (which turned out to be a bad assumption). When I gave `/etc/arbitrary1` an execute perm that matched www-data (with either `chown www-data:www-data /etc/arbitrary1` or `chmod o+x /etc/arbitrary1`), the map worked fine.